# How do you say you felt the same when someone said they were delighted: Do you say " "So, did I" OR "So was I."?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language, collocations, colloquial-language

This is from a tv show [Golden Ladies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auhCTAJHg2M&list=PLZVOlsj5n3xGMCBAvdvDO9juBK-8wVTk3) (see:13:21-13:25) The ladies are talking about their new neighbours(the McDowells) who were there and have just left.

**Blanch: Well, I think the McDowells were delightful.**

**Rose: I did too.**

**Dorothy: So did I.**

Rose and Dorothy were delighted, too. However they used a different structure when they said this.

As far as I know, Rose should have said **"I was too."** and Dorothy should have said **"So was I."**, but they used **"did"**.

Is it something colloquial?

Comment: "I was too" would definitely be wrong: "do/did" substitutes for a verb (here, "think") in this kind of construction. Why do you think that "was" is better? (I thought you were going to ask about the different tenses they used, which is another issue.)

Comment: If Rose said "I was too", she would be claiming that ***she was also "delightful"*** (as were the McDowells) - which is syntactically valid, but an unlikely thing to say! But your examples are weird anyway, because of the non-idiomatic switch from Present to Past Tense

Comment: @StuartF, I did not think they were referring to the verb "think", I thought they were referring to "being deligtful", which is why I expected an answer like "So was I", because I focused on "They were delightfull".  I thought both Rose and Dorothy meant "I am delighted, too". But now I understand, they are referring to the verb "think". But then yes, as you said, why did they use a different tense? why did not they say "So, do I" or "I do, too"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes you are right. I seemed to switch from Present to Past, because I mistakenly focused on the second sentence "...they were deligtful" rather than the first part "I think", which is why I expected an answer in the past. Interestingly, why did Rose and Dorothy use a different tense from the tense of "I think ...."? Should they not have said "So, do I" or "I do, too".

Comment: Yeah - that TV show is just sloppy writing (and/or sloppy acting). People wouldn't normally switch tenses like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She says **I think they were delightful**, not **I was delighted with them**!!

So, **I did too** means **I thought so too**, not **I was delighted too**.

It does seem odd that the others reply in the past tense when Blanche used the present tense. They answer as though she had said **I thought**, which would be more usual. (She thought so while she was in their company.) Maybe the actress made a slight error which wasn't important enough for the director to notice.

Comment: yes I missed that point and you completely understood how I interpreted it and why I asked such a question. I mistakenly interpreted Blanch's sentence as if she meant "I was delighted with them.", which she did not.

Comment: It's a bit weird that Blanch says "think....were" instead of "thought...were" or "think...are".